# Reference specific column for function

Tags: excel, vba, function, reference

I am trying to remove the `CellRef As Range` as a parameter so the user just needs to enter the function name. How do I reference an absolute column with a relative row? (i.e. `$G4`).

```
Function CO_NAMEREFORM(CellRef As Range) As String
    '=LEFT($G4,FIND("/",$G4)+1)
    CO_NAMEREFORM = Left(CellRef, InStr(CellRef, "/") + 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Don't do that.  The formula then will not update as the cell updates.  The whole reason to put it in the argument is to capture when it changes and recalc this function.  You can make it volatile but that means it will now recalc every time Excel recalcs whether the target value changed or not.  this can slow down the response after every change to Excel as it has to recalc this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Application.ThisCell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.thiscell).

```
Public Function CO_NAMEREFORM() As String
    Application.Volatile

    With Application.ThisCell
        Dim CellRef As Range
        Set CellRef = .Parent.Range("G" & .Row)
    End With

    '=LEFT($G4,FIND("/",$G4)+1) 
    CO_NAMEREFORM = Left(CellRef.Value, InStr(CellRef.Value, "/") + 1)  
End Function
```

But in my opinion (and others') this is a **bad** idea - as @Scott Craner pointed out, now the function has to be volatile and this just increases overhead.

Comment: Scott, what does the ```.Parent``` represent?

Comment: It represents the worksheet that the function is called in.